# Turning JSON file into HTML radio quiz

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I need to fetch JSON file, sort it's Question,Possible aswers and then display correct answer but I cant fetch and sort it properly

```
    <script>
            fetch("quiz.json").then(function (response) {

                response.json()

            }).then(function(quiz){
                for(let i = 0; 1 <quiz.length; i++){
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<h2>' +quiz[i].question + '</h2>';
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<imput type="radio">' +quiz[i].options ;
                    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' +quiz[i].answer + '</p>';
                }
            })
    </script>
```

When I try it it says "

````
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at (index):30:40
```"

JSON file :
````

{
"quiz": {
"q1": {
"question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
"options": [
"New York Bulls",
"Los Angeles Kings",
"Golden State Warriros",
"Huston Rocket"
],
"answer": "Huston Rocket"
},
"q2": {
"question": "'Namaste' is a traditional greeting in which Asian language?",
"options": [
"Hindi",
"Mandarin",
"Nepalese",
"Thai"
],
"answer": "Hindi"
},
"q3": {
"question": "The Spree river flows through which major European capital city?",
"options": [
"Berlin",
"Paris",
"Rome",
"London"
],
"answer": "Berlin"
},
"q4": {
"question": "Which famous artist had both a 'Rose Period' and a 'Blue Period'?",
"options": [
"Pablo Picasso",
"Vincent van Gogh",
"Salvador Dalí",
"Edgar Degas"
],
"answer": "Pablo Picasso"
}
}
}

```
Also Im using XAMPP and only vanilla js
```

Comment: you're missing a `return` in your first callback. tip, shorten it to `resp => resp.json()` instead of `function(response){return response.json()}`

Comment: Quiz isn’t an array, so it doesn’t have a length property.

Comment: You're not returning anything in the first promise chain of fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data to

```
{ "quiz": [
        { "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?", "options": [ "New York Bulls", "Los Angeles Kings", "Golden State Warriros", "Huston Rocket" ], "answer": "Huston Rocket" },
        
        { "question": "'Namaste' is a traditional greeting in which Asian language?", "options": [ "Hindi", "Mandarin", "Nepalese", "Thai" ], "answer": "Hindi" }, 
        
        { "question": "The Spree river flows through which major European capital city?", "options": [ "Berlin", "Paris", "Rome", "London" ], "answer": "Berlin" }, 
        
        { "question": "Which famous artist had both a 'Rose Period' and a 'Blue Period'?", "options": [ "Pablo Picasso", "Vincent van Gogh", "Salvador Dalí", "Edgar Degas" ], "answer": "Pablo Picasso" } 
    ] 
}
```

that will make `quiz` an array, and then you can navigate it with your code.